# Plugins for gvim only?

Tags: vim

How do you prevent a plugin from loading in command-line vim, but allow it to load in gvim?

I'm trying to use `gitgutter`, which has these lines at the top:

```
    if exists('g:loaded_gitgutter') || !executable('git') ||  !has("gui_running") || &cp
       finish
    endif
```

However, every time I start up vim on the command line in a git-enabled directory, I get all this junk:

```
"plugin/gitgutter.vim" 416L, 11964C
Error detected while processing function GitGutter..<SNR>35_init..<SNR>35_define_signs:
line    7:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version:     sign define GitGutterLineAdded           text=+  texthl=lineAdded    linehl=NONE
line    8:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version:     sign define GitGutterLineModified        text=~  texthl=lineModified linehl=NONE
line    9:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version:     sign define GitGutterLineRemoved         text=_  texthl=lineRemoved  linehl=NONE
line   10:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version:     sign define GitGutterLineModifiedRemoved text=~_ texthl=lineModified linehl=NONE
Error detected while processing function GitGutter..<SNR>35_find_other_signs:
line    2:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: :sign place file=/Users/adam/.vim/plugin/gitgutter.vim
Error detected while processing function GitGutter..<SNR>35_show_signs..<SNR>35_add_sign:
line    3:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: :sign place 3000 line=1 name=GitGutterLineModified file=/Users/adam/.vim/plugin/gitgutter.vim
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: My question was somewhat invalid - turns out, my edited `if` statement was both correct and worked, BUT there was a copy of gitgutter in my bundle/ directory that was loading in place of the `plugin/gitgutter.vim`

Answer (score 1):

You should be testing `has('signs')` and not `has('gui_running')`

```
:h +signs
```

Comment: Adding this test had no effect; I think the issue may perhaps not be with my test for signs vs gui_running, but that the finish command seems to be ignored.

Comment: What I found odd is that vim is telling you `:sign` is not supported in your version of vim. What does `:echo has ('signs')` tell you ? I guess you'll see 0, which should cause `finish` to be executed. Don't hesitate to add traces with `:echomsg` in your plugin. You will quickly see which of your assumptions was false.

Comment: The `if` statement should definitely be evaluating to `true`: `has('gui_running')` and `has('signs')` are both 0.  But I still get the `E319` messages.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but you added `|| !has('signs')` right? (With the exclamation mark)